# IIS 8 with PHP7 does not found Firebird/Interbase driver

Tags: php, iis

I run a IIS8 Webserver on Windows 2012 with PHP 7.0.5.

I my `php.ini` i have the following included

```
extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

These files are in the `ext` folder (by default shipped with php7). I restartet the server, but the firebird and interbase extensions are not showed in my `phpinfo()`.

They showed me only in the `Module Authors` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting FBCLIENT.dll into `windows/system32` folder...